# Do I need an internal Load Balancer for my ECS Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an `ECS` cluster with 3 services(`FARGATE`), the 3 services are in private subnets. 1 is the web app that is publicly accessible through an Internet-facing Load Balancer and the 2 others are only accessed from the web app. For internal communication, I'm using Service Discovery names.
[image]

Everything is working but now I'm debating if I need an internal Load Balancer just between the web app and the 2 internal services in case they scale out/in. So, if one of my internal services scales out and I'm using the Service Discovery name for internal communication, it is enough? Or, do I need an internal Load Balancer that can route the traffics to the different service instances?

Does this make sense?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Service Discovery is enough. New nodes will be added to the SD name resolution when they are started. Unfortunately many people don't know / use Service Discovery and resort to the more expensive ALB. Good on you for using SD :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, so what exactly happen when my downstream private service scaleup? The SD will take care of load balancing it?

Comment: I don't think you'll see the right behavior. DNS queries typically will be cached on the application, and it will work, but if your application scales quickly, you'll need to wait for the DNS TTL for nodes to become aware of the newly available addresses in the registry. ALB I think is faster to respond to scale out and scale in.

Comment: When using Service Discovery, the load-balancing responsibility is transferred to the client making the request. If the Web app does not load balancing on its side, then all requests sent using the Service Discovery URL will be serviced by the same task. @MLu how is it a better solution than using ALB? 

Answer (score 1):

Cloud map by itself does not support features like sticky sessions that you get from application load balancers. Cloud map also can't do round robin routing like load balancer does to its target groups.

So, for simpler use cases in which you don't care about let's say sticky sessions, using cloud map without ALBs might suffice.